# Print all lines of file and matching lines from other file

Tags: file, awk, grep

I have file1 and file2. I want to print all lines of file1 and if: column 1 and 2 of file1 match columns 1 and 2 of file2, then: adds that line from file2 to line of file1.

```
File1:
1  30  40  name  info
1  3  2  desc  info
1  3  2  id  info
10  35  45  name  info 

File2: 
20 30 40 numbers  desc
1  3  2  desc name 

Result:
1  30  40  name  info  -
1  3  2  desc  info  desc name 
1  3  2  id  info  desc name 
10  35  45  name  info  -
```

I did this code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1,$2]=$0;next}{print h[$1,$2],$0}' file1.txt file2.txt > result.txt
```

But it only prints lines that match and I want all lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this awk one-liner should help:

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2}
  NR==FNR{a[k]=$4FS$5;next}{printf "%s %s\n", $0, (k in a?a[k]:"-") }' file2 file1
```

Comment: `printf` not necessary: `print $0, (k in a?a[k]:"-")`.